# Unable to start daemons using start-dfs.sh

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

We are using cdh4-0.0 distribution from cloudera. We are unable to start the daemons using the below command.

```
>start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
hduser@localhost's password: 
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory `/hduser': Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access `/hduser/hduser': No such file or directory
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /hduser/hduser/hadoop-hduser-namenode-canberra.out
localhost: /home/hduser/work/software/cloudera/hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.0.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 150: /hduser/hduser/hadoop-hduser-namenode-canberra.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open `/hduser/hduser/hadoop-hduser-namenode-canberra.out' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Take a look the error messages. No permission to create folders etc. ?

Comment: The product is installed as hduser and is running as hduser and we checked all HADOOP_* configuration parameters, they seem to be fine. Is there a way to print debug logs while the command is being run.

Comment: It looks you missed to check if the ssh hduser@localhost works without password (usually by public key authentication is mentioned in the docs as far as i know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using tarballs?

Try to set an override the default `HADOOP_LOG_DIR` location in your `etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` config file like so:

```
export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=/path/to/hadoop/extract/logs/
```

And then retry `sbin/start-dfs.sh`, and it should work.

In packaged environments, the start-stop scripts are tuned to provide a unique location for each type of service, via the same `HADOOP_LOG_DIR` env-var, so they do not have the same issue you're seeing.

If you are using packages instead, don't use these scripts and instead just do:

```
service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start
service hadoop-hdfs-datanode start
service hadoop-hdfs-secondarynamenode start
```