# unable to start start-dfs.sh in Hadoop Multinode cluster

Tags: hadoop

I have created a hadoop multinode cluster and also configured SSH in both master and slave nodes now i can connect to slave without password in master node

But when i try to start-dfs.sh in master node I'm unable to connect to slave node the execution stops at below line

log:

```
HNname@master:~$ start-all.sh
starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-HNname-namenode-master.out
HDnode@slave's password: master: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-HNname-datanode-master.out
```

I pressed Enter

```
slave: Connection closed by 192.168.0.2
master: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-HNname-secondarynamenode-master.out
jobtracker running as process 10396. Stop it first.
HDnode@slave's password: master: starting tasktracker, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-HNname-tasktracker-master.out

slave: Permission denied, please try again.
HDnode@slave's password:
```

after entering the slave password the connection is closed

Below things I have tried but no results:

1. formatted namenode in both master & slave node
2. created new ssh key and configured in both the nodes
3. override the default HADOOP_LOG_DIR form the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540591/unable-to-start-daemons-using-start-dfs-sh) post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you missed this step "Add the SSH Public Key to the authorized_keys file on your target hosts"

Just redo the password-less ssh step correctly. Follow this:

1. Generate public and private SSH keys

   ```
   ssh-keygen
   ```
2. Copy the SSH Public Key (`id_rsa.pub`) to the root account on your
   target hosts

   ```
   .ssh/id_rsa
   .ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ```
3. Add the SSH Public Key to the `authorized_keys` file on your target
   hosts

   ```
   cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
   ```
4. Depending on your version of SSH, you may need to set permissions on
   the `.ssh` directory (to 700) and the `authorized_keys` file in that
   directory (to 600) on the target hosts.

   ```
   chmod 700 ~/.ssh
   chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```
5. Check the connection:

   ```
   ssh root@<remote.target.host>
   ```

   where `<remote.target.host>` has the value of each host name in your cluster.

   If the following warning message displays during your first
   connection: Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

   Enter Yes.

Refer: [Set Up Password-less SSH](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.2.0.0/bk_Installing_HDP_AMB/content/_set_up_password-less_ssh.html)

Note: password will not be asked, if your passwordless ssh is setup properly.

Comment: Yes this should fix issu, coz clearly passwordless ssh was not setup correctly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to start hadoop services with a new user called hadoop.

Then make sure to add the public key to the slaves with that new user.

If this doesn't work, check your firewall or iptables

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

That mean you haven't created public key properly.

Follow below sequence.

1. Create User
2. Give all required permissions to that user
3. Generate public key with same user
4. Format Name Node
5. Start hadoop services.

Now it should not ask for password.