# Does Hadoop require ongoing password-less ssh access once installed and daemons running?

Tags: linux, bash, security, hadoop, ssh

The directions for starting Hadoop in a multi-node cluster call for provisioning of password-less ssh access between systems so that the hadoop startup scripts can start appropriate daemons on the (namenode, datanodes, and secondarynamenode).

- Does Hadoop requre password-less ssh access once installation and daemon startup complete?
- Once the software is installed and the daemons are running, can I relinquish ssh access between cluster systems?
- Does Hadoop (&Hdfs) require this ssh access to remain?
- What does Hadoop use this password-less access to accomplish?
- Is ssh access only for starting daemon processes?

I have been reading the start-up scripts, and there seems to be need for bi-directional ssh (slaves perform rsync from master, master sends commands to start daemons to slaves).

[unable to start start-dfs.sh in Hadoop Multinode cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921761/unable-to-start-start-dfs-sh-in-hadoop-multinode-cluster)

[Unable to start daemons using start-dfs.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540591/unable-to-start-daemons-using-start-dfs-sh)

[Set Up Password-less SSH - Automated Install with Ambari](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.2.0.0/bk_Installing_HDP_AMB/content/_set_up_password-less_ssh.html)

Comment: The stop scripts require SSH as well. If your servers ever restart, you therefore still need SSH access.

Comment: If you are using Ambari, it communicates via the agents, not SSH. *You can choose to manually install the Agents on each cluster host. In this case, you do not need to generate and distribute SSH keys.*